# Curvy hard surface

Tags: topology, nurbs-surface

I am running into a bit of a struggle here with a curved surface and was wondering if anyone could provide a tip to mode this. I highlighted the panel in green and the curved '' flow'' in orange.

Thanks in advance!
[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Use your picture as a Reference image, draw the mesh:

[image]

Switch to side view, pull the front and back edges on the Y axis (here you're a bit forced to guess what's happening as you don't have any side view of your object):

[image]

Add edge loops to curve the inside:

[image]